# StaleObjectStateException on high frequency updates

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss6.x

We're using Hibernate 3.6.3.Final and MySQL 5.5.8 for a web application. The backend is running on a JBoss 6.0.0 Final server. Most of the time things work really well but occasionally we're getting a StaleObjectStateException. After a while of experimenting we figured out that it can be reproduced by sending requests to the backend with a high frequency (ie. clicking a button which triggers the request as fast as possible).

As far as I know the exception means that a domain object got fetched from the database and when Hibernate tried to persist it again it noticed that another transaction changed it in the meantime.

However as far as I understand databases the conflicting transactions should be isolated to an extent which prevents exactly this behavior. I explicitly changed the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE which guarantees repeatable reads and I disabled Hibernate caching. This should prevent the situation where one transaction sees different versions of the same domain object.

The full stack trace is:

```
    2011-04-28 20:46:17,865 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (WorkerThread#2[127.0.0.1:57772]) ARJUNA-12125 TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff7f000001:126a:4db9c7b0:74d, org.hibernate.transaction.synchronization.HibernateSynchronizationImpl@481efbaf >: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [xxx.modules.domain.entity.User#118]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1243) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1166) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1153) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$3.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1067) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.transaction.synchronization.CallbackCoordinator.beforeCompletion(CallbackCoordinator.java:122) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.transaction.synchronization.HibernateSynchronizationImpl.beforeCompletion(HibernateSynchronizationImpl.java:51) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:97) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:94) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:159) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1158) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:119) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:82) [:0.0.1]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:255) [:0.0.1]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:349) [:0.0.1]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:209) [:0.0.1]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.aop.CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.java:52) [:0.0.1]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76) [:1.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42) [:1.0.3]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:182) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67) [:1.0.1]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:392) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.session.InvokableContextClassProxyHack._dynamicInvoke(InvokableContextClassProxyHack.java:53) [:1.7.17]
        at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:91) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82) [:1.0.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:898) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:791) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:744) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:586) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:234) [:6.0.0.Final]
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [xxx.modules.domain.entity.User#118]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1932) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2576) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2476) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2803) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:113) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383) [:3.6.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.transaction.synchronization.CallbackCoordinator.beforeCompletion(CallbackCoordinator.java:117) [:3.6.0.Final]
        ... 39 more
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance
Michael

Comment: More implementation details would help. For example, is the data submitting code multi-threaded, how do you create and close sessions?

Comment: The frontend requests are processed in stateless session beans in the JBoss AS which handles the database transactions. The server is multi threaded which means that each request will run in its own thread. The JBoss AS is supposed to process each frontend request in its own database transaction and the Hibernate log suggests that this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you **very**, **very** sure that you've set the TX to serializable? Because that should never happen on a serializable transaction.

If two TX read and modify the same row in a serializable transaction, then oracle throws an [ORA-08177](http://ora-08177.ora-code.com/).

Please check that hibernate is actually setting the TX as serializable.

#### Edit

You can do what Jonas suggested or you can also check it from you application by getting the underlying connection and invoking Connection.getIsolationLevel(). For example

```
Connection c = session.connection()
int level = c.getIsolationLevel()
```

#### Edit 2

Ok, since you confirmed that the isolation level on the Connection is SERIALILIZABLE, could you check:

- That the tables are using the innoDB engine.
- As Jonas suggested, run `SELECT @@tx_isolation;` from your code while it is in the transaction. It should return *SERIALIZABLE*. This is to check that the Connection is actually propagating the isolation level. It's a bit paranoid, but what to do...
- Check that your code only opens one transaction, and runs everything in that TX. I just tested the SERIALIZABLE isolation level manually and it works as expected (it blocks any TX trying to read the same row).
- Last resort: check that the isolation level SERIALIZABLE works on your MySQL installation.

**NOTE**: As I mentioned before, MySQL will block any queries trying to read from the same row. That means that if you have some "common tables" such as country, company, user, etc. that many TXs read concurrently, it might make your app run almost sequencially rather than parallelly.

Comment: I set the property `hibernate.connection.isolation` to `SERIALIZABLE`. Is there a way that I can verify that the isolation level is really set correctly?

Comment: `SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html

Comment: Please see the update ... and I just realized that you're using MySQL... I thought you were using oracle... I need a new pair of glasses.

Comment: getTransactionIsolation() returns 8 (= Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE).

Comment: Please check the 2nd update... you have a nice problem in your hands :D

Comment: I just noticed that my local test DB was using MyISAM instead of InnoDB. After converting all tables to InnoDB and ensuring that the isolation level is SERIALIZABLE I now get the expected behavior: DEADLOCK. Thanks a lot for all your replies!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have configured Hibernate to use [optimistic concurrency control](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic). That means that your User table has a version field that Hibernate increments on every row update.

Most likely your transaction starts at the beginning of the HTTP request and ends a the end of the HTTP response. This means that the process of editing a user consists of two transactions: one transaction to populate the web form and one transaction to save the changes.

In that case, changing the isolation level of the database will not do any good. Most likely all you will get is [worse performance and scalability](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/2/10/database-isolation-levels-and-their-effects-on-performance-a.html).

It is not a bad thing to have `StaleObjectException`s. It reflects the real world - people do actually work on the same thing once in a while and conflicts may occur. The question is, when a conflict has been detected, how do you resolve it in a manner that is satisfying to the end users? Can it be resolved without the assistance of the user?

Possible strategies could be to

- overwrite the previous user's changes
  (often not what you want - hence the need for concurrency control),
- show an error message asking the
  user to refresh and perform his
  changes again,
- automatically merge the changes without overwriting the previous user's changes (sometimes possible)
- inform the user about the staleness
  of his data and offer him a way to manually merge his changes

It all depends on the context.

Comment: You're right, we're using optimistic concurrency control. However the backend works in a way that it loads an object from the database, applies some changes and persists it again. All within the same database transaction. As far as I understand Hibernate's optimistic concurrency control it should only throw a StaleObjectException if you fetch an object from the DB in one transaction, apply some changes and persist it in another transaction. As repeatable read is guaranteed by the database it should not happen that the version field changes within the same transaction... Right?

Comment: @Miichaal yes, you're right, Oracle should return the same data or an oracle error. Another question would be if you're running everything as part of the same transaction or if you're opening one to read the row and another to write the row.

Comment: Hi Augusto, unfortunately the code which deals with all of that isn't from me so I'm not 100% sure if my assumptions are correct. We're interacting with Hibernate using a class called CrudServiceBean which is annotated with @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED). This class makes use of an EntityManager which in turn is annotated with @PersistenceContext(unitName = "xxxDb", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION). My interpretation is that the JBoss opens a new transaction for each request and the EntityManger in turn opens a new DB transaction for each JBoss transaction.

Comment: Try to activate MySQL's general query log. This allows you to see when a transaction is started and stopped. Maybe it will reveal something unexpected. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html

Comment: Sry it took me so long! I finally managed to enable the MySQL log and the request is definitely processed withing the same transaction. I also verified that the isolation level is set to SERIALIZABLE. Any clues?

Comment: Are all the involved tables using the same storage engine? Which engine is being used? `InnoDB`, `InnoDB Plugin` (different from the former), `MyISAM`, or something else? You can see it by using `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>`.