# OptimisticLockException in JBossAS-7

Tags: exception, ejb, jboss7.x

I'm getting the an `OptimisticLockException` when I try to update a managed entity EJB.

The EJB was fetched via:

```
port = entityManager.find(PortEntity.class, portID);
```

and then the EJB and the entityManager has been passed to a SAX `ContentHandler` so that in the `endDocuent()` method it can be updated.  The `ContentHandler` has extracting the time zone information from the data returned from Google's [Time Zone API server(s)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/).

The code snippet is:

```
entityManager.refresh(port);
if (entityManager.contains(port))
    log.info("Contained: " + port);
else
    log.info("NOT Contained: " + port);

port.setTimezone(toTimezone);
entityManager.flush();   // <-- Line 70
```

And the log file show:

```
13:48:05,568 INFO  [GeotimezoneHandler] Status: OK
13:48:05,569 INFO  [GeotimezoneHandler] Raw offset: 3600.0000000
13:48:05,570 INFO  [GeotimezoneHandler] DST offset: 0.0000000
13:48:05,570 INFO  [GeotimezoneHandler] Timezone ID: Europe/Madrid
13:48:05,571 INFO  [GeotimezoneHandler] Timezone Name: Central European Standard Time
13:48:05,577 INFO  [GeotimezoneHandler] Contained: SeaPort[id=ESBCN, name=Barcelona]
13:48:05,591 ERROR [GeotimezoneHandler] Updating curise: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.nutrastat.voyager.entity.PortEntity$Sea#ESBCN]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1390) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1308) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:976) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.flush(AbstractEntityManager.java:439) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at com.nutrastat.voyager.util.GeotimezoneHandler.endDocument(GeotimezoneHandler.java:70) [voyager-lib.jar:]
```

So if the `entityManager` contains the EJB why after modifing it do I get the exception?

As always many thanks for your help

Steve

P.S.

I have looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825161/staleobjectstateexception-on-high-frequency-updates) and The MySQL database is using InnoDB, but I don't know how to execute the `SELECT @@tx_isolation;` command from within my code.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of research I finally found what the problem was.

The entity class inherited from its superclass a `javax.persistence.Version` field.  I had also hand injected data into the table, and because the version field was defined as allowing nulls had not bothered to insert a value, but one was needed.